# Join table with order by and group by

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT c_id, user_id, message, state, time FROM message 
WHERE receive=1 
ORDER BY message_id DESC
)AS t GROUP BY c_id
```

I have mysql statement can fetch out last message for user.

however i need to join the user table, so i can fetch out the sender's name

```
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id=message.user_id
```

How to achieve this?

```
//user
user_id name

//conversation
c_id    user_id

//message
m_id    c_id    user_id(sender) receive message state   time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT c_id, user_id, message, state, time 
    FROM message 
    WHERE receive=1 
    ORDER BY message_id DESC) AS t 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id=t.user_id 
GROUP BY c_id
```

P.S. check if user.user_id exists.